# PGFPLOTS: Drawing a Histogram

Tags: pgfplots

I know the answer will be straightforward, but I've been wading through large numbers of examples and can't seem to find just what I want.

I'm setting an exam for my Statistics students, and one of the questions has a histogram for them to interpret. I've entered the data as coordinates, and am now trying to set the ticks on the x-axis to the edges of the bars, rather than set in the middle of the bar. Here's my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ybar interval, ymax=55,ymin=0, minor y tick num = 3]
\addplot coordinates { (0, 5) (5, 35) (10, 50) (15, 30) (20, 15) (25, 0) };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which produces this nice image:

[image]

What I'd *like* is to have the x-values at the left-hand edge of each bar, and have the final value (25) appear on the right-hand edge of the last bar. I can manually move the x-values using something like

```
xticklabel style = {xshift=-0.6cm}
```

but this breaks if I change the width of the histogram, and still doesn't get the last value displayed. I've also tried manually setting the xticks with

```
xtick = {0, 5,..., 30}
```

but that still doesn't make the “25” appear. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Something like this?

[image]

Above picture is produced by:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,
               tikz,
               preview
               ]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

    \begin{document}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ymin=0, ymax=55,
    minor y tick num = 3,
    area style,
    ]
\addplot+[ybar interval,mark=no] plot coordinates { (0, 5) (5, 35) (10, 50) (15, 30) (20, 15) (25, 0) };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```