# Bar chart with `tikz-pgf` specifying the breakpoints between cells

Tags: tikz-pgf, bar-chart

I would like to draw, with `tikz-pgf`, a bar chart by specifying the breakpoints between histogram cells and the corresponding frequencies. The breakpoints are:

```
 -1.4 -1.2 -1.0 -0.8 -0.6 -0.4 -0.2  0.0  0.2  0.4  0.6  0.8  1.0  1.2  1.4  1.6
```

whereas the frequencies:

```
8    19   106   322  1242  3190  6028 10610  1690  1260   502   160    34     6     1
```

For example, between -1.4 and -1.2 we have 8, between -1.2 and -1.0 we have 19 and so on.

Comment: I think your questions isn't very clear. So, when x is between -1.4 and -1.2 to have a bar of 8?

Comment: @Y_gr: yes, a bar of 8 between -1.4 and -1.2, a bar of 19 between -1.2 and -1.0 and so on...

Comment: What do you mean by specifying breakpoints? Is it manually? Or by setting some interval? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/273817/pgfplots-drawing-a-histogram Does it answer your question?

Comment: @M.A.Bromuela: yes, it answers my question! Thank you!

Comment: Than we can conclude, that your question is actually duplicate?

Comment: Yes, it is. Should I delete it?

Comment: No, not needed. You can remove bounty and than close it is as duplicate.